# How do I create and use an interface using: interface, dictionary and constructors?

Tags: javascript, interface

I am trying to design an easy to use interface with high affordance (i.e it will help you not to enter wrong information).

I have watched the documentation for the Tizen web-api and I really like the structure. The thing I cant figure out is. Is the information on the page implementation or just the documentation? Here is an example: [ContactName](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.device.apireference/tizen/contact.html#%3a%3aContact%3a%3aContactName) and [ContactNameInit](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.device.apireference/tizen/contact.html#%3a%3aContact%3a%3aContactNameInit)

`ContactName` is an object you can create in javascript and `ContactNameInit` makes it easy to do so. To create a `ContactName` you can write `var name = new ContactName({firstname: "james"});` and this will create the object with the attribute firstname as james.

The approach uses defined types/classes and (if the documentation is implementation) simple use of the `interface` word.

This is the only example of interface I think is worthy of implementing. I have found some links where interfaces are implemented via created objects which in my opinion is not an interface, and other alternatives which looks wrong (though they might be the right way?). Examples: [Interface in Javascript](http://www.javascriptbank.com/how-implement-interfaces-in-javascript.html), [Object oriented Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter8.html).

I would like to implement the following (this code does not work):
(functional copy of [Tizen web-api Contact](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.device.apireference/tizen/contact.html#%3a%3aContact%3a%3aContact))

```
dictionary CarInit{
    DOMString model;
    // more attributes etc.
}

[Constructor(optional CarInit? carInitDict), Constructor(DOMString stringRepresentation)]
interface Car{
    attribute DOMString? model;
    // more attributes and methods, foo() for example.
}
```

Do I need to implement more stuff in my API to get this code to work? Can I get this code to work, or is it just documentation?

At Tizens page there is a lot of these `´type´?` which means requires input to be of type. Is this javascript standard, documentation or just something they use?

If all of this above is wrong.
What is the easiest approach for desired effect? The main issue I want is a constructor for an object so that you can write: `var foo = new bar({foobie:value, barbie:value})` etc.

Comment: The code block after "I would like to implement the following" isn't JavaScript or anything close to it. It might be some form of IDL.

Comment: That's what I though first aswell, but then I saw the Tizen documentation. Is that all it is? Documentation easy to read? Cause if it is, why use psuedo-code javascript?

Comment: @ Yokich: As I say, it may be some form of IDL, but it has nothing to do with JavaScript. IDL has utility because it lets you express these things in a language-independent way (as the DOM and HTML5 specs do for the DOM API). That's useful for documentation, and also for automation (e.g., automatically generating code skeletons for objects that conform to the IDL). But JavaScript doesn't have anything like that built into it, that's a separate thing.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will start implementing my duck-analyser promptly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have interfaces at all. The usual approach to interfaces is documentation combined with "duck typing" — e.g., an API accepts an object and provided the object "walks like a duck and talks like a duck" (has the relevant methods and/or properties on it), the API is happy with that object.

If you want to use strong typing, JavaScript isn't the language for you. You might consider [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/), which is a language built on JavaScript that adds typing, and which is then "compiled" into JavaScript for deployment (e.g., so it will run in browsers and other environments that support JavaScript). But how well that will work for you depends on how you're publishing the API, how it's being consumed.

Another option is to have a "developer" mode for your API where it does lots of checks on the objects to make sure they conform to an expected set of methods and properties, and then a "release" or "runtime" mode where it assumes things will be fine (to avoid the runtime performance penalty of the checks).

Comment: I recognize and acknowledge the "duck typing", I've seen it before. I suppose I can create the constructor in such a way that it (probably with some help functions) checks an object as parameter for "walks" and "talks"- it should work.
I just thought that what Tizen's doc was doing looked like a simple solution. Would you mind take a look at the "Tizen web-api Contact"-link and see what you can find out?